# How to calculate RMSE for a non linear model?

Tags: statistics, nonlinear-system, mean-square-error, nonlinear-analysis

I am doing a project in which I need characteristics for signal strength to distance. I have done measurements and made a curve fit of mean values. For a log-plot the model becomes linear and an RMSE value can be calculated.

Log Distance Model = -0.02872*x - 0.2217

RMSE = 0.0527

RMSE lines = -0.02872*x - 0.2217 $\pm$RMSE

[Log Distance Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPat6.jpg)

However, when transforming the Log Distance Model to a Non-Log Distance Model, to get the real distances in meters. The upper and lower RMSE boundaries are not equal in magnitude ( $|$+RMSE$|$ $\neq$ $|$-RMSE$|$ ).

Non-Log Distance Model = 10^(Log Distance Model).

Non-Log RMSE lines = 10^(RMSE lines)

[Non-Log Distance Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soA18.jpg)

Am I doing it wrong? If so, how should I get RMSE values for the Non-Log Distance Model?

If it is correct, how is it logical that the  $|$+RMSE$|$ $\neq$ $|$-RMSE$|$ ?

Best regards

Comment: To be clear, your initial model is $y=10^{ax+b}$ ? Then you linearize to obtain a log-linear model.

Comment: My first model is the Log Distance Model. Which I obtained from Matlab's curve fit tool after I have taken the 10-logarithm of the distance values. The reason why is because Matlab could not find a good fit for my samples in the initial non-log form.

Comment: If I look at the graphs both regression lines seems fine. But in general what you do if you have a exponential model is that you  linearize the model to obtain a log linear model. For this purpose you transform the y-values: $y'=\log_{10}(y)=ax+b$. Then you can apply linear regression (with Matlab).

Comment: That is exactly what I have done and as you say the Non-Log Distance Model (Non-linear) fits well. My question was that the RMSE lines differ in magnitude from the regression line, in the Non-Log Distance Model. Example:
Regression line at -100 dBm = $10^{-0.02872*(-100) - 0.2217} = 447$ .
RMSE Lines at -100 dBm = $10^{-0.02872*(-100) - 0.2217 \pm RMSE}$ = 505 and 396.
$|505-447| \neq |396-447|$